# How do I extract particular name from a file name in shell

Tags: shell, unix

In shell scripting Suppose I have a file name called aaa_djdidm_cjcjcj_20220602.txt

I only want the name except the date.
Expected result - aaa_djdidm_cjcjcj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the part after the last `_`:

```bash
NAME="aaa_djdidm_cjcjcj_20220602.txt"
NEW_NAME=${NAME%_*}
```

The `%` operator is useful do remove the motif (here `_*`) of a named parameter (here `NAME`)